# Identification of model of an old auto

Tags: old-cars

So, my friend has sent me an image of an old car she met in the street.
Can anyone help me to identify its model? Or maybe just give hints on what I shall search to find it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. How about some context? Where was the image taken (country/region)?

Comment: Hi, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ! Thank you for hospitality. It was seen in the Russian Far East, so it's in Russia near China and Japan

Comment: I'm not finding anything ... too bad we couldn't see the front of the car. Some points of interest. The doors are not "suicide" style doors, which were very common for the 40's era vehicles. You can just barely see it, but the front fender line extends into the front door. It also has a wing window in the front as well as the window behind the rear door. This is not an American car, as far as I can tell, but has American style influence.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thank you very much for at least some pointers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **1946 or maybe 1947 Chevrolet Stylemaster Sport Sedan.** The big hint is almost not in the picture -- and it's that part of the wheel arch styling built into the front door.  The other model with such a feature that comes to mind is the Oldsmobile of that era, but the Olds arch came almost all the way to the back of the front door and this is only part way.

In 1946, there were no outside mirrors, so that's obviously aftermarket.  Also, the rear bumper is wrong and those ugly, bulbous rear lights were NOT in the original style.  Here's an ad for a similar model (Fleetmaster) from 1947, from http://www.oldcaradvertising.com/Chevrolet/1947/1947%20Chevrolet%20Ad-06.jpg

[image: ad for 1947 Chevrolet Fleetmaster Sport Sedan]

If I'm not mistaken, the difference between the Fleetmaster and the Stylemaster was the the latter had a little less chrome, notably around the windows.  The one in your picture appears to have none of the original chrome, so it's hard to tell exactly which model it was.

Also, as an additional note.  These were made in the US and also in Australia with Holden.  Given where yours was located, the original source could have been either country.

Comment: Yes, i agree with Edward. i think it is a **1948 Chevrolet Stylemaster Sport Sedan Police Car**. [reference](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/myoldpostcards/tags/stylemaster/)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a conglomeration of different cars.  I see an XM radio antenna on the rear roof and what look like modern side mirrors.  I agree with @Paulster2; this is not an US-made car.  If you can find a picture book or guide of some kind, I would look for Russian sedans made in the late 1930s thru 1940s.

Not sure this helps you any....:(

Comment: ..and no way that's an original chrome bumper considering the condition of the rest of it.